# Images appearing corrupted in Chrome/Brave browser for a few moments

Tags: google-chrome, images, brave

In the past few weeks I've started to see images appear in my browsers (both Brave and Chrome) infrequently as below.
[image]

They will appear like this for a few moments, then refresh to show the correct image.

Piqued my interest as hadn't seen it before.

Is this something wrong my end, such as a graphics card issue or Chrome/Brave rendering issue?

Comment: I have the exact same happening. Have not been able to find a pattern as to when it happens, what triggers it, whether its image specific etc.

Comment: I cannot remember how I fixed it now, I want to say I updated my graphics drivers, but  I could be misremembering. Sorry!